# Constantly losing Wifi with version 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am now using version 16.04. Wifi keeps crashing for unknown reasons. I have never experienced this issue with previous versions

My wireless card is PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? If you'd like assistance with your 3945, I will be very happy to help. I own one and it works well.

Comment: Well, I guess it was more of a  comment or rant as I am really annoyed with this so called version (16.04)  And I am tired in asking for help on this issue.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the result of the network diagnostic;

Comment: Sorry, I am having difficulty attaching the diagnostic file ???

Answer (score 3):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
sudo modprobe iwl3945 swcrypto=0
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwl3945 swcrypto=0"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf
exit
```

Comment: I will give your last suggestions a try.